# Get difference in hours between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, crystal-reports, psql

How can I subtract two dates (`entry_date` from `status_change_date`) to get hours between them? I do this based on an IF statement where both dates are in `YYYY,MM,DD 12:00:00` format

```
(IF Invoice_Num != next Inv_Num then entry_date - status_change_date else...
```

It returns an answer in days instead of hours. I also tried using `minutes(entry_day)` and `hours(status_change_date)` in Crystal after the code was done, but I still got day values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @startDate datetime
declare @endDate datetime

set @startDate = '2016-12-05 08:05:00';
set @endDate = '2016-12-05 09:52:00';

select CONVERT(varchar(3),DATEDIFF(minute,@startDate, @endDate)/60) + ':' +
          RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(2),DATEDIFF(minute,@startDate,@endDate)%60),2)
          as TotalHours
```

Check this example, get the hours and minutes between to datetime vars

Answer (score 2):

From document [**TIMESTAMPDIFF(unit,datetime_expr1,datetime_expr2)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff),

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2016-12-05 12:00:00', '2016-12-06 12:00:00');
```

This will get you 24 hours.

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/87119)**